# How to list 'AAA','AAB','AAC'.......'ZZZ' with a SQL Server query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I need to update 12.000 records in a table to put them in order with 'AAA', 'AAB', 'AAC'.....'ZZZ'. It should be 3 characters.

The table looks like this:

table_items

```
id - int (Identity)
name - nvarchar(50)
picking_order - nvarchar(3)
```

I need to update `picking_order` with 3 chars. How can I code this script in SQL Server?

Comment: Do you have to update existing records or insert new records?

Comment: I have to update the existing records

Comment: Just a though, can your table increase the number of registries? Because with this combination of yours, you can only have 17576 permutations if my calculations is correct.

Comment: Also you can not "order" a table. The only way to get a specific order in a query is to use `Order by`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `ASCII()` function and some arithmetic:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*, row_number() over (order by id) - 1 as seqnum
      from t
     )
update toupdate
    set picking_order = (ascii(char('A') + seqnum / (26*26)) +
                         ascii(char('A') + (seqnum / 26) % 26) +
                         ascii(char('A') + seqnum % 26)
                        );
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you can do - long way (Gordon's got a really cool way to do what you want)

- create a stored procedure
- set a variable to 0
- use a [while loop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178642.aspx) from 65 to 90
- inside that, create another while loop that goes from 65 to 90
- inside that, create another while loop that goes from 65 to 90
- select top 1 id into variable from table where id > variable
- update table set field = char(loop-1-number) + char(loop-2-number) + char(loop-3-number) where id = variable.  See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7d/536

After your loops are done, your record will be updated

Comment: While Loops?! in SQL!? WHYYYYYY NOOOOOO

Comment: SQL is based on set theory, not functional programming. Using a while loop is like walking a bicycle.

Comment: Gordon already had a SQL-based answer. I offered other means of solving the problem. Databases are a lot more than just SQL. My answer uses stored procedure and I feel While has a use case - just like there's a use case of walking a bike through certain areas of my township.

Comment: We're going to have to *seriously* agree to disagree.